# before send in $.ajaxSetUp not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        if(settings.type == "POST")
            settings.data = $.extend(settings.data, {test:"One" });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hi,
I want to add data {test:"One"} to each and every ajax call from that page if the request/type is post . But for some reason above code is not working. What's wrong with above code.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What does "is not working" mean exactly?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to assign to `settings.data`, since `$.extend()` modifies the object in place.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can handle this using the [`ajaxPrefilter()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) function, which is designed to handle any modifications that need to be made to requests prior to them being sent:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
   // If this is a POST, then add to it
   if(originalOptions.type == 'POST' || options.type == 'POST') {
       options.data = $.extend(originalOptions.data, { test: 'One' });
   } 
});
```

Comment: I am user Jquery 1.4 where prefilter is not available. If i am not working prefilter came into ajax from 1.5